# Get length of only files not including folder

Tags: node.js

Get the length of the files not including folder.

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.readdir(process.cwd(), function(err, files) {
   console.log(files.length);
}
```

I have written the code but code includes the folder. I don't want to count the folder

Comment: you want file content length

Comment: No, just files length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fs.readdir` function fetches the list of files and folders within the given directory. In order to filter only files from the list and ignore directories, you need to implement an additional check using the `fs.statSync("path").isFile()` function.

The below code should give you the desired results.

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.readdir(process.cwd(), function(err, contents) {
  var files = [];
  contents.forEach(function(f) {
    if(fs.statSync(f).isFile()) {
      files.push(f);
    }
  });
  console.log(files.length);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Retriving files count in a directory can be achieved by using fs.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const dir = './directory';
fs.readdir(dir, (err, files) => {
  console.log(files.length);
});
```

Comment: I want only file count not folder